# GridFS issues with a Mongo Import

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have a production server running Mongo 2.0.7 and a local machine that runs Mongo 2.0.6.

I exported a database as a JS file and then imported it in my local machine. EVerything seems to be working fine however I am unable to server GridFS files. That is when I try accessing that resource, I get corrupt data and thus no image. Any thoughts? I tried looking at the change log for the version change and saw nothing that could effect that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you used mongoexport to produce the JSON dumps.  mongoexport does not provide the same data fidelity as mongodump, so try that instead.